# How to guarantee atomicity of nested objects while saving model instance?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

Here's my code:

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    is_crawler = models.BooleanField()


class Wheel(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='wheels', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    radius = models.IntegerField()


class WheelSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wheel
        fields = '__all__'


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    wheels = WheelSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'
        
    def validate(self, attrs):
        is_crawler = attrs.get('is_crawler')
        wheels_data = attrs.get('wheels')
        if wheels_data and is_crawler:
            raise ValidationError("Crawler can't have wheels")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        is_crawler = attrs.get('is_crawler')
        wheels_data = attrs.get('wheels')
        car = Car.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for wheel_data in wheels_data:
            wheel_serializer = WheelSerializer(**wheel_data)
            if wheel_serializer.is_valid():
                wheel_serializer.save()
        return car
```

So, when I'm trying to send something like

`{"is_crawler": true, "wheels": [{"radius": 5}]}`
to CarSerializer it raises ValidationError that causes 400 response from the view.

But it doesn't prohibit creating wheels for crawlers in admin for example. Is there a way to transfer validation from serializer to model's `clean` or `save` method to prohibit creating crawler cars with wheels or add wheels to crawler cars in any part of code? And if there is, will it raise the same ValidationError in DRF and return HTTP_400 from DRF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `clean` method to your models but it won't be called in your serializers. This is made on purpose for separation of concerns as explained in the [DRF 3.0 announcement](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#differences-between-modelserializer-validation-and-modelform).

Here is your code with the clean methods on `Car` and `Wheel`, with some small changes to make it work on my side.

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    is_crawler = models.BooleanField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_crawler and self.wheels.count():
            raise ValidationError("Crawler can't have wheels")


class Wheel(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name="wheels", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    radius = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.car.is_crawler:
            raise ValidationError("Crawler can't have wheels")


class WheelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wheel
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("car",)


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    wheels = WheelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, attrs):
        is_crawler = attrs.get("is_crawler")
        wheels_data = attrs.get("wheels")
        if wheels_data and is_crawler:
            raise ValidationError("Crawler can't have wheels")
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        wheels_data = validated_data.pop("wheels")
        car = Car.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for wheel_data in wheels_data:
            wheel = Wheel.objects.create(**wheel_data, car=car)
            car.wheels.add(wheel)
        return car
```

As said in the docs you could also instanciate your model in the `validate` method of the serializer, but it's discouraged.

```py
def validate(self, attrs):
    instance = ExampleModel(**attrs)
    instance.clean()
    return attrs
```